Javascript function passing htmlcollection unexpectedly
I am trying to pass two variables into a javascript function:-
$newsuitID = $row2->new_suit_id;
$page = 'allSuits';
echo "<tr class='$highlight' onclick='trclickNewsuit($newsuitID,$page);'>";

My function receives the number without issue and I can alert it, or log it to the console, however the string doesn't return as a string. It returns as an object HTML Collection. I have tried various methods of obtaining the value and all of the research I have undertaken points to looking at the DOM, however I just want to pass the value.
This is my function testing, ultimately the purpose of the function is to do something with the value, or cancel and do something with the text.
alert(newSuitID); 
alert(page);
var string = newSuitID;
var cancel = page;
//var cancel = HTMLCollection.blah[0];
console.log(string);
console.log(cancel);

My questions are:
I don't understand why I am getting the HTMLCollection object when I pass a text string, so is there something I should be doing that I am not?
Is there a way of getting the value out of the HTML Collection? I can see the value in the console within the HTML Collection object.

Edited to add more explicit code.

Look at the duplicates linked above. You want something like this to ensure you pass values correctly: printf('<tr class="%s" onclick="%s">', htmlspecialchars($highlight), htmlspecialchars(sprintf('trclickNewsuit(%s, %s);', json_encode($newsuitID), json_encode($page))));. See https://kunststube.net/escapism.

Try this:
onclick='doSomething($newsuitID,"$page");'

Reason: You're not delimiting the string properly.
Update: based on additional details added to the question:
As you mentioned this is wrapped in PHP, do this:
echo "<tr class='$highlight' onclick='trclickNewsuit($newsuitID,\"$page\");'>";

I simply escaped the double quotes.

That is assuming $page isn't a Javascript variable, but interpolated from some other language (like PHP), and the value happens to match some Javascript variable… Possible, but conjecture. Also, if that was the case, there'd be better ways to pass that value, like using echo json_encode($page) or something.

@deceze I completely agree, I only inferred so because OP said he is getting the correct integer value for $newsuitID. That is why seemed like delimiter is the probable issue here.

@deceze - it is indeed being passed by PHP. I'll edit my question to show more code.

@Jason in case does the above solve your problem?

@subdeveloper - not yet, but this is probably because my code is wrapped in a PHP tag, so the double quotes cause mischief. I'm working out how to delimit / move the relevant part into HTML. As you can probably tell, I am not a developer, so basic stuff sometimes stumps me.

@Jason updated my answer, this will help you surely! JFYI it's called escape sequence and it's used to escape the characters from being treated specifically as per the language.

@subdeveloper - perfect this has it. Thank you. I find all the variations of escape sequence very confusing. This is very useful.
